# What is effectiveness of methyl-alcohol as sporicide?

Tags: microbiology, mycology, medicinal-chemistry, sterilisation

Methyl-alcohol is the weakest alcohol in terms of bactericidal properties. However, I have read that it also works as sporicide.

What is the effectiveness of methyl-alcohol in killing the spores of fungi and bacteria compared to other substances and what is the best dilution?

Comment: Are you specifically looking out for fungal spores, or do bacterial spores work too?

Comment: I would say that a little bit of information about also the bacterial spore is not useless... Question edited! @MarchHo

Comment: From page 233 of [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=3f-kPJ17_TYC&pg=PA233#v=onepage&q&f=false): *Bacillus anthracis spores resist methanol completely at concentrations of 0.004% to 95% but are killed by ethanol in 48h at concentrations of 42% to 100%.* Methanol can be oxidized to formaldehyde (which is a disinfectant) but this reaction cannot be performed without certain catalysts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methanol (methyl alcohol) tends to lack sporicidal activity on its own. However, fresh mixtures of **methanol and hypochlorite**, with at least 15% methanol, are known to have *low* sporicidal activity.

With an increasing methanol concentration, right up to about 50% methanol, the sporicidal activity can be increased. The preparation, however, isn't overly stable and the sporicidal activity will start to decrease after 8 hours. It is thus recommended, should a methanol + hypchlorite mix be used to counteract spores, to only use a freshly prepared solution of 50% methanol and a sufficient amount of (sodium) hypochlorite that provides 2000 parts per million available chlorine in distilled water and allow for a contact time of at least 15 minutes.

Sources:

1. [Russell 1990 - Bacterial Spores and Chemical Sporicidal Agents](http://cmr.asm.org/content/3/2/99.full.pdf+html)
2. [Kelsey JC, Mackinnon IH, Maurer IM Sporicidal activity of hospital
       disinfectants Journal of Clinical Pathology 1974;27:632-638.](http://jcp.bmj.com/content/27/8/632.info)